# Entity Framework - The foreign key component … is not a declared property on type

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I have the following Model

```
public class FilanthropyEvent :  EntityBase, IDeleteable
{  
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Target { get; set; }
    public decimal EntryFee { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    public ICollection<EventAttendee> EventAttendees { get; set; }
}

public class Attendee : EntityBase, IDeleteable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool MailingList { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    public ICollection<EventAttendee> EventAttendees { get; set; }
}
```

Events and Attendees is a many to many relationship but I needed another property on the association so I created an association entity

```
 public class EventAttendee : EntityBase
 {
    public int FilanthropyEventId { get; set; }
    public int AttendeeId { get; set; }
    public bool InActive { get; set; }

    public virtual Attendee Attendee { get; set; }
    public virtual FilanthropyEvent FilanthropyEvent { get; set; }
 }
```

These are the configurations for each FilanthropyEvent and Attendee

```
public class FilanthropyEventConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<FilanthropyEvent>
{
       public FilanthropyEventConfiguration()
       {
           HasKey(x => x.Id);
           Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

           HasMany(x => x.EventAttendees).WithRequired(x =>      x.FilanthropyEvent).HasForeignKey(x => x.FilanthropyEvent);
       }
}

public AttendeeConfiguration()
{
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        HasMany(x => x.EventAttendees).WithRequired(x => x.Attendee).HasForeignKey(x => x.AttendeeId);
}

public class EventAttendeesConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<EventAttendee>
{
    public EventAttendeesConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(x => new {x.FilanthropyEventId, x.AttendeeId});
    }
}
```

When I try and initialise the database via  the `update-database` command in the package manager console I get the following error.

> System.InvalidOperationException: The foreign key component 'FilanthropyEvent' is not a declared property on type 'EventAttendee'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid primitive property.

I realise I'm probably missing a mapping in the `EventAttendeesConfiguration` class but what would be the correct mapping to model this relationship?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This code

```
HasMany(x => x.EventAttendees)
.WithRequired(x => x.FilanthropyEvent)
.HasForeignKey(x => x.FilanthropyEvent);
```

Should be

```
HasMany(x => x.EventAttendees)
.WithRequired(x => x.FilanthropyEvent)
.HasForeignKey(x => x.FilanthropyEventId);
```

Comment: `Blimey(...)` -- should be an exception type. I did the same thing ... `Doh(...)`

Comment: :( guess this is a common stupid error, done the same as well, i blame copy and paste :)